# Include text from one apt to another apt

Tags: java, maven, documentation-generation, apt, doxia

Imagine I have three apt files:

main.apt

```
Info, details, etc..

    some text

Configuration

    some text
```

child1.apt

```
Info, details, etc..

    some text

Configuration

    [Same text as MAIN.APT configuration]
```

child2.apt

```
Info, details, etc..

    some text

Configuration

    [Same text as MAIN.APT configuration]
```

I want to follow DRY(don't repeat yourself) principle and to reuse text from main.apt and to add it to child1.apt and to child2.apt. This would really help writing documentation.

I have tried using snippets (Firstly generated site documentation with id's and then added references to those id's):

```
~~START SNIPPET: id
~~END SNIPPET: id
%{snippet|id=id|url=http://svn.example.com/path/to/main.html}
```

And generated site using

```
     mvn site:stage
```

, but this is not working, because it inserts block of html text, which is not being formatted as html. I also tried verbatim parameter in snippets, it does not help.

Maybe someone has a solution for this problem and/or faced the same problem? Please tell me your story, suggestions. Solution would save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#parse). Rename child1.apt and child2.apt to child1.apt.vm and child2.apt.vm respectively. Then replace

> ```
> [Same text as MAIN.APT configuration]
> ```

with

```
#parse("main.apt")
```

In *site.xml*  include child pages like any other:

```
<item name="child 1" href="child1.html"/>
```